# TypeScript 1.5: ES6 Module default import of CommonJS 'export =' (.d.ts only issue?)

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm encountering an issue with:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

`moment` itself is a function that is a default CommonJS export, as coded here https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/moment/moment.d.ts:

```
interface MomentStatic {
    (): Moment;
    (date: number): Moment;
    ...
}
declare var moment: moment.MomentStatic;
declare module 'moment' {
    export = moment;
}
```

The following do not seem to work:

```
import * from 'moment';
// error TS1005: 'as' expected.
// error TS1005: 'from' expected.

import moment from 'moment';
// error TS1192: External module ''moment'' has no default export.

import {default as moment} from 'moment';
// error TS2305: Module ''moment'' has no exported member 'default'.
```

The require syntax still works... but I'm trying to avoid that.

```
import moment = require('moment');
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The syntax you are looking for

```
import * as moment from "moment";
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not correct, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29598404/252087

Comment: Thanks. I've asked for a clarification : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242#issuecomment-92218146

Comment: @CSnover I've marked this as a duplicate and pointed to your answer :heart: