# Typescript import node_modules with ECMAscript 6 syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript

I installed the library **lodash** from npm and now i want to import it to my file like this:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

But i get this error:

> Error TS1192: Module '"lodash"' has no default export.

Why I get this error? and how I can import **node_modules** that are not .ts files with the new import syntax of ECMAscript6?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596714/new-es6-syntax-for-importing-commonjs-amd-modules-i-e-import-foo-require/29598404#29598404

Answer (score 5):

The following two approaches works for me:

Using **require**:

```
/**
 * Install package via
 *   $ bower install lodash --save
 * Run:
 *   $ node test.js  # after TypeScript compilation
 */

// test.ts file
/// <reference path="typings/lodash/lodash.d.ts" />
import _ = require('./bower_components/lodash/lodash.js');
console.log(_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2));
```

ES6 **import**:

```
/**
 * Install package via
 *   $ tsd install lodash --save # to download definition file
 *   $ npm install lodash --save
 * 
 * Run:
 *   $ node test.js  # after TypeScript compilation 
 */
// test.ts file
/// <reference path="typings/lodash/lodash.d.ts" />
import * as _ from 'lodash';

console.log(_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2));
// → [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

Note: Path mappings based module resolution planned for TypeScript 1.8 (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039)

Comment: But how typescript knows from where to pull the lodash library based on the definition file?

Comment: Check this line: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/lodash/lodash.d.ts#L9983 and you can see that the name 'lodash' is defined there, so no error is thrown on line `import * as _ from 'lodash';`. TypeScript compiler does not pull anything (check the compiled `test.js` file).