# How to convert reference path to ES6 import in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Recently took up learning Typescript and came across a annoyance (due to compiler constantly picking it up).

I currently have the following line to use jQuery:

```
///<reference path="jquery.d.ts"/>
```

Yet my tslint tool always marks it as red and advises to use ES6 imports instead.

How can I convert the reference that I have into a proper ES6 import for my typescript file to consume?

Comment: Check out this answer to a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119270/should-i-use-es6-import-or-reference-path-when-loading-typescript-definition-fil

Comment: Yep seen it before, I'm still keen to know how to import that jquery.d.ts using ES6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply convert your reference to:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

and everything *should* **Just Work <sup>(TM)</sup>**

Comment: Good enough gave me the right direction to look into. Thanks