# Node.js + TypeScript: Unclear syntax with type script compiled code

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-module-loader

I'm trying to work with TypeScript in my node project, but I have some issues with that.

This is my *index.ts* file:

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
```

I'm running:

```
tsc --module commonsjs -d index.ts
```

My output is *index.js*:

```
var express_1 = require('express');
var app = express_1["default"]();
```

Where did this `["default"]` came from? It is making my code not to run properly:

```
var app = express_1["default"]();
                              ^

TypeError: express_1.default is not a function
```

As far as I understand, I should have got the code without the "default" brackets and it would have worked fine - I tried removing the brackets and it worked.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Module should be `commonjs` and not `commonsjs`. That may be causing you a problem.

Comment: Consider using esModuleInterop: true compiler option (set it on your tsconfig). This allows you to do `import express from 'express'` as you would expect

Comment: instead of `import express from 'express'` you could also try `import * as express from 'express'` - which one will work usually depends on _esModuleInterop_ setting in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The safest solution would be:

```
import express = require('express');
```

This transpiles to:

```
var express = require('express');
```

The official documentation for import require declarations can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/376534981220fbbfee39ae97299aafe0d9c473ce/doc/spec.md#11.3.3).

I believe TypeScript expects an export named "default" to function as your code above, judging from the final paragraph [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/376534981220fbbfee39ae97299aafe0d9c473ce/doc/spec.md#11342-export-default-declarations).

---

Side note: It looks like TypeScript's newest version (typescript@1.8.0-dev.20151229 at the time of writing) will throw a warning on a compile attempt which would attempt to use a missing default:

```
index.ts(1,8): error TS1192: Module '"express"' has no default export.
```

---

Side note 2: An example from Microsoft using the `import * as express from 'express';` syntax can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/blob/f206e7ca3e0f605ee5ec8f9b30894881dbe4c462/imageboard/app.ts#L3). When targeting a module of `commonjs` (as [they are](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/blob/f206e7ca3e0f605ee5ec8f9b30894881dbe4c462/imageboard/tsconfig.json#L3) in this example), this will also transpile to `var express = require('express');`.

---

If you have at least TypeScript 2.7 and are targeting CommonJS, you can use [esModuleInterop](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-2-7/#easier-ecmascript-module-interoperability), as well.

From the link:

> To give users the same runtime behavior as Babel or Webpack, TypeScript provides a new --esModuleInterop flag when emitting to legacy module formats.
>
> Under the new --esModuleInterop flag, these callable CommonJS modules must be imported as default imports like so:

```
import express from "express";

let app = express();
```

> We strongly suggest that Node.js users leverage this flag with a module target of CommonJS for libraries like Express.js, which export a callable/constructable module.

Comment: `import *` is the wrong way to import legacy modules. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29598404/252087.

Comment: Consider using esModuleInterop: true compiler option (set it on your tsconfig). This allows you to do `import express from 'express'` as you would expect

Answer (score 39):

I solved this by adding the following to `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ... 
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    ...
  }
}
```

The **esModuleInterop** flag is described as: "Emit __importStar and __importDefault helpers for runtime babel ecosystem compatibility and enable --allowSyntheticDefaultImports for typesystem compatibility."

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: This solved my problem! Could've known [ts-node-dev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev) is using TypeScript's configuration, so I added a `tsconfig.json` file. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it allows to simply use `import express from 'express'`

Comment: I agree this is the correct strategy with newer versions of typescript. This option wasn't made available until typescript 2.7, which came out in 2018.

Answer (score 7):

If you are trying to use the default export of a non-ES6 module like Express.js, you need to use the legacy import syntax `import express = require('express')`.

In ES6 modules, there is no default value export like the `module.exports` of Node.js modules or the `return` of AMD modules; the default export of an ES6 module is just the `default` key. This is why, when you use an ES6 default `import` as you are attempting to do, TypeScript generates JavaScript with an access to the `default` property.

More information about this is available at *[New es6 syntax for importing commonjs / amd modules i.e. `import foo = require('foo')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596714/new-es6-syntax-for-importing-commonjs-amd-modules-i-e-import-foo-require)*.

Comment: Thanks! I had some research on the subject thanks to you.

Comment: I don’t understand why you accepted the other answer as the correct answer. It’s the wrong answer.

Comment: If it is truly the wrong answer for the current version of Typescript, then I suggest you have Microsoft edit their examples.

Comment: @dvlsg That Microsoft example is *not* the same as what the OP is doing! The example uses only the `static` property from `express`, it does *not* try to use the default export (because it couldn’t, because it’s wrong and won’t work). In such a case, `import *` is fine, because it makes the imported `express` identifier a blank List, then adds all exported properties of the express module onto that List, per the ES specification. It *not* correct for using the default export.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `const app = express();` in the original question is exactly what is being done in the Microsoft [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/blob/f206e7ca3e0f605ee5ec8f9b30894881dbe4c462/imageboard/app.ts#L11) (minus the const, of course). I agree that `require` will work in more scenarios, however, so I will edit accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that line. That really should not be working, since the ES spec is explicit that the value of a `* as` import is [a Namespace Object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-module-namespace-objects), not any callable item, and implementation of ES6 modules syntax was [supposed to disallow it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29598404/252087). So I’m trying to track down when and how the semantics of `* as` were changed to not fail in this case.

Comment: Perhaps it allows it because my test environment and their example were both aiming for `commonjs` (for better or worse or unintentionally)? Targeting ES6 with no module defined resulted in error TS1202 (import assignment cannot be used), but does attempt to transpile. ES6/ES5 with commonjs as the module both transpiled to `var express = require('express');`. Targeting ES5 with no module defined doesn't even attempt to transpile, and suggests setting a module.

Answer (score 5):

If you still want to use the `import` keyword then use it like:

```
import express from "express"; 
// If the above is not supported by your project environment then follow as below
import * as express from "express";
```

In file `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...   
    "module": "commonjs"
    ...
  }
}
```

Thanks to [Josh Dando](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520288/nodejs-typescript-unclear-syntax-with-type-script-compiled-code#comment97379861_52772480).

Comment: Make sure to have "module": "commonJS" in your tsconfig.json

Answer (score -1):

Another solution that could work for you is do it like this:

```
import * as express from express;
const app = express();
```

It should work in the same way.