# TypeScript Importing from libraries written in ES5 vs. ES6

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, commonjs

I get weird errors when running *transpiled* TypeScript code that depends on external libraries

Such as `Uncaught TypeError: es5_lib_1.default is not a function`

What's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New es6 syntax for importing commonjs / amd modules i.e. \`import foo = require('foo')\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596714/new-es6-syntax-for-importing-commonjs-amd-modules-i-e-import-foo-require)

Comment: indeed, thanks! I will add this answer to that question, basically the same as the 1st answer but more drawn out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ES6 module spec differ slightly from CommonJs, described [Here](http://www.jbrantly.com/es6-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack/#importinglibraries). This introduces some compatibility issues that are somewhat exasperated in TypeScript.

TypeScript tries to guess the correct way to transpile `import/require` statements based on two inputs

- The `module` property in `tsconfig.json`
- How the `export` statement is written in the corresponding `.d.ts` file

In the `tsconfig.json` file, we can set module format the transpiled output will use. For example, `module: 'es6'`

What we choose here have an impact on the kind of importing syntax TypeScript will allow. Which also impacted by how the corresponding `.d.ts` shape files are written.

#### If we are *Importing From* a CommonJS library and Our Output module targets CommonJS, we must use

```
//tsconfig.json
module: "commonjs"

//.d.ts
declare module 'foo' {
    exports = Foo;
}

// App.ts
import Foo = require('foo');
```

#### If we are *Importing From* a CommonJS library and Our Output module targets ES6, we must use:

```
//tsconfig.json
module: "es6"

//.d.ts
declare module 'foo' {
    exports default Foo;
}

// App.ts
import {default as Foo} from 'foo';
```

#### If we are importing *From a ES6* library, we can use the `import {default ... }` style regardless of the targeted Output module format

```
//tsconfig.json
module: "es6|commonjs"

//.d.ts
declare module 'foo.es6' {
    exports default FooES6;
}

// App.ts
import {default as FooES6} from 'foo.es6';
```

#### What does this mean for `.d.ts` files we retrieve from `tsd install`?

Depending on which output we are targeting, we may have to alter the `.d.ts` files after they've been installed to suit our needs. Most `.d.ts` files are written for `commonjs` modules and thus will use the `export = <lib>` style. But if you want to target ES6 output, you will need to edit this like and change it to `export default`

#### Please Provide Corrections to this Answer as Needed