# How to import CommonJS module that uses module.exports= in Typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript1.7

The following produces valid, working ES5 but emits the error below. I'm using Typescript 1.7.5 and I think I've read the whole language spec and I cannot figure out why this error is produced.

```
error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
```

**a.js** (ES5 ambient module with default export)

```
function myfunc() {
  return "hello";
}
module.exports = myfunc;
```

**a.d.ts**

```
declare module "test" {
    export default function (): string;
}
```

**b.ts**

```
import test = require("test");
const app = test();
```

**b.js (generated ES5):**

```
var test = require("test");
var app = test()
```

Comment: What line is this error on?

Comment: Line 2 of test.ts. at test()

Comment: BTW, pretty confusing that your post uses the base name "test" for all three of your files. The third file, that imports "./test" and is called "test.ts", is surely actually something else. :)

Comment: @CSnover I agree it's unclear, so I've edited the file names to `a` and `b`. `a` is an ES5 commonjs module with no preexisting type declaration file. `b` is typescript consuming `a`. Also, the `require()` in `b.ts` is changed from `"./test"` to `"test"` as it should be a string literal for an external ambient module. I'm surprised it worked with `"./test"` as the relative path to `test.js`, but it worked. But this is better because it's the recommended way from the Typescript spec.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`module.exports` exports a literal value in a CommonJS module, but `export default` says you are exporting a `default` property, which is not what your JavaScript code actually does.

The correct export syntax in this case is simply `export = myfunc`:

```
declare module "test" {
    function myfunc(): string;
    export = myfunc;
}
```

Comment: That works. Thank you. I think the Typescript spec really led me astray here. Regarding export assignments it says, "Export assignments exist for backward compatibility with earlier versions of TypeScript." ([reference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#1135-export-assignments)), implying it's the old way and you should not use export assignments in new code. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622598/typescript-importing-from-libraries-written-in-es5-vs-es6) is closely related.

Comment: Also, for the future reader, `module.exports=` in ES5 is **not** a "default export", which is an ES6 term. Typescript spec explains the `default` entity [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#11342-export-default-declarations).

Comment: AFAICT doing this requires `"esModuleInterop": true` in your TS compilerOptions. Or am I doing something wrong?