# module.exports in typescript file return 'module is not a module.'

Tags: typescript

The following module written in JS file:

```
module.exports = {
  propA: 1,
  propB: 2
}
```

Allows later to import the property from the module like:
`import { propA } from 'path/to/module'`

However changing the format of the file to typescript like `module.ts` results in the following issue linter issue 'module is not a module.'

Here is the tsconfig for the project

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I will appreciate if somebody can suggest a valid way to preserve module.exports or in typescript :)

...or at least a possibility to declare the module that exports object in the way that later is allowed to import only it's single property

Comment: This might help:https://stackoverflow.com/a/35401923/5271656

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import CommonJS module that uses module.exports= in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398633/how-to-import-commonjs-module-that-uses-module-exports-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
export const yourData = {
  propA: 1,
  propB: 2
}
```

and import yourData from 'yourSrc'