# Module '...' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I have a .tsx file in which I am trying to import a RaisedButton component from material-ui like so:

```
import * as RaisedButton from 'material-ui/lib/raised-button'
```

However, that gives me the error described in the title, any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: How are you exporting things from `raised-button`? And what module format are you using?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is from the `material-ui.d.ts` file.

```
export import RaisedButton = __MaterialUI.RaisedButton; // require('material-ui/lib/raised-button');
```

So you should import it like this.

```
import RaisedButton = require('material-ui/lib/raised-button');
```

Comment: Yep, I got it working. Could you also explain why that is? Is this a new standard of exporting/importing modules? What is the difference between import x from '...' ; import * as x from '...' and import x = require('...') ?

Comment: It can be confusing. The new import syntax is for ES6 modules. require() is for AMD/CommonJS, which material-ui is doing using export default {}. This answer can it explain it better. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596714/new-es6-syntax-for-importing-commonjs-amd-modules-i-e-import-foo-require/29598404#29598404