# Cannot find declaration file for 'autobind-decorator' in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I am using Typescript and I want to import 'autobind-decorator' package inside project but ı stuck here.

I am getting this error line while compiling:

> cannot find declaration file for 'autobind-decorator'. Implicitly has an 'any' type

I also tried `@types/autobind-decorator` npm package, but it didn't work.
Is there any option to get rid of this compile error ?

Here is my tsconfig:

```
{
    "version": "2.1.5",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["es2015", "es2016", "dom"],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "react",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    },
    "include": [
      "./packages/ld-web/src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "**/node_modules",
        "**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

import :

```
import * as autobind from "autobind-decorator";
```

Comment: can you add your import statement and also your tsconfig.json content to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the type declarations [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/autobind-decorator/index.d.ts) it declares and exports as module,

You need to install the `@types` as:

```
npm install @types/autobind-decorator --save-dev
```

and import as:

```
import autobind = require("autobind-decorator");
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I tried this. In this case, I am getting this error : Module ''autobind-decorator'' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct :(

Comment: I tried both of the import statement. That doesn't change anything.

Comment: Yes. I found the solution here, our import statement is wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277354/module-resolves-to-a-non-module-entity-and-cannot-be-imported-using-this-c

Answer (score 0):

This worked, not using import at all:

```js
const { autobind } = require('autobind-decorator');
```

I still had errors at runtime, so I read the doc again

https://www.npmjs.com/package/autobind-decorator

and used

const { boundMethod } = require('autobind-decorator');

that works,

I tried again using import and it failed.