# Typescript import from ES2015 export: how to specify type declaration file

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, feathersjs

I'm trying to make a sparse type declaration file for feathersjs so I can better use it in Typescript.

Feathers is written in ES2015 and distributes ES5 (via Babel).
The ES5 default export:

```js
function createApplication() {
  var app = express();
  Proto.mixin(Application, app);
  app.init();
  return app;
}
module.exports = createApplication;
```

My type declaration file (feathers.d.ts):

```
declare module "feathers" {
    import * as express from "express";
    import * as serveStatic from 'serve-static';

    interface Feathers extends express.Express {
        (func?: express.Express): Feathers;
        setup(): Feathers;
        static: typeof serveStatic;
    }

    var createApplication: Feathers;

    export default createApplication;
}
```

My app (server.ts):

```
import feathers from "feathers";
const app = feathers();
app.use('/', feathers.static(__dirname)).listen(3001);
```

So far, typescript compiles with no errors, I get all the nice type checking help in the IDE (atom-typescript). Typescript compiles to the following ES5, which does not run because of the `.default()` resulting from the default export. 
(server.js):

```
var feathers_1 = require("feathers");
var app = feathers_1.default();
app.use('/', feathers_1.default.static(__dirname)).listen(3001);
```

If I change the import statement to:

```
import * as feathers from "feathers";
```

Then the type checking fails and the compiler emits errors, but it does produce running ES5:

```
var feathers = require("feathers");
var app = feathers();
app.use('/', feathers.static(__dirname)).listen(3001);
```

The typescript compiler errors are:

```
error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
error TS2339: Property 'static' does not exist on type 'typeof "feathers"'.
```

**Question**: Which of the below `import` statements should be used in this case? Or, what's wrong with the declaration file (listed above)?

```
// import feathers from "feathers"; // no errors, but emits .default object
// import * as feathers from "feathers"; // errors, but working ES5
// import feathers = require("feathers"); // errors, but working ES5
const app = feathers();
app.use('/', feathers.static(__dirname)).listen(3001);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing typings for a CommonJS module so don't use `export default`, instead do this:

```
declare module "feathers" {
  // ...

  var createApplication: Feathers;
  export = createApplication;
}
```

And then import it like this:

```
import feathers = require('feathers');
// OR
import * as feathers from 'feathers';

const app = feathers();
app.use('/', feathers.static(__dirname)).listen(3001);
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I found the distinction in the Typescript spec ([11.3.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#1135-export-assignments)):  "An export assignment designates a module member as the entity to be exported in place of the module itself." compared to [11.3.4.2](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#11342-export-default-declarations) which says "Export default declarations provide short-hand syntax for exporting an entity named `default`."

Comment: The accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596714/new-es6-syntax-for-importing-commonjs-amd-modules-i-e-import-foo-require is also worth a read.