# TypeScript declaration for NodeJS modules which exports a class

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to write typescript declaration file for `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, but I can't get it working.

`HtmlWebpackPlugin` default export is the constructor for class `HtmlWebpackPlugin`. I plan to use it like this.

**somefile.ts**

```
import * as HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({..some options...})
```

I tried defining it as follows

**shim.d.ts**

```
/// <reference path="./shim.d.ts"/>
declare module 'html-webpack-plugin' {
  interface Options {
    title: string,
    filename: string,
    template: string,
    inject: (boolean | 'head' | 'body'),
    favicon: string,
    hash: boolean,
    cache: boolean,
    showErrors: boolean,
    chunks: any,
    chunksSortMode: ('none' | 'auto' | 'dependency'),
    excludeChunks: any,
    xhtml: boolean
  }
  class HtmlWebpackPlugin {
    constructor(options: Options);
  }
  export default ???
}
```

I wonder what to fill in `???` here. I tried exporting `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, `typeof HtmlWebpackPlugin`, but nothing works. It gives me the following type error.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
   export { HtmlWebpackPlugin };

   // or you may directly export class

   export class HtmlWebpackPlugin {
     constructor(options: Options);
   }
```

Comment: I don't think this work. HtmlWebpackPlugin is the default export in Node.JS, so the export of HtmlWebpackPlugin in the declaration should be default as well.

Comment: I've updated my question in case you want to take a look

Comment: yes you are right this will not work `new HtmlWebpackPlugin({..some options...})`, i checked if you use `import * as X from "html-webpack-plugin";` and then `new X.HtmlWebpackPlugin({..})` works. Let me try if it may be used directly.

Comment: i just tried  `export default HtmlWebpackPlugin;` and using it as 'import HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin"; let x = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({});' it works. what is the eroor you are getting?

Comment: Take a look at your compile result and you'll see where it goes wrong. It compiles to `var x = require('html-webpack-plugin');` and `new x.default({..})`, which I don't think works in Node environment.

Comment: Can confirm that behavior is (or was) intentional at one point, both with babel and typescript, where `module.exports = Something` is intentionally not the same as `export default Something` for interoperability reasons (I think). Don't have an answer for you, though, since I'm not sure how to solve this unless you are the owner of `HtmlWebpackPlugin`. More reading [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596714/new-es6-syntax-for-importing-commonjs-amd-modules-i-e-import-foo-require/29598404#29598404).

Comment: Thank you very much, I finally figure out how to do it!

Answer (score 0):

The `import * as Module from 'module'` form no longer works for AMD/CommonJS for better interoperability with ES6 modules (which uses this form to export the entire namespace).

Solution:

Make `HtmlWebpackPlugin` export non module entity by default.

```
declare module 'html-webpack-plugin' {
  interface Options {
    title: string,
    filename: string,
    template: string,
    inject: (boolean | 'head' | 'body'),
    favicon: string,
    hash: boolean,
    cache: boolean,
    showErrors: boolean,
    chunks: any,
    chunksSortMode: ('none' | 'auto' | 'dependency'),
    excludeChunks: any,
    xhtml: boolean
  }

  export = class HtmlWebpackPlugin {
    constructor(options: Options);
  }
}
```

Import it using the required style

```
import HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
```