# How to add an external js file in my angular2 project

Tags: angular

I am using the angular cli repo. I want to add external js file. I don't want to add it directly with  tags in the index.html.

I have the main.js file in a folder call js in the assets folder. assets/js/main.js.

How can I do add this to work in all my components?

Comment: you add path of file js in "scripts": [ ]  in angular-cli.json

Comment: ts but I was thinking of using a js file within. Is that even okay?

Comment: Just realized you are using angular cli.. Nothing stopping you from using `js` file. If it's your own then see if this question for help http://stackoverflow.com/q/37639820/1339516