# ReactJS + typescript - could not import react-autosuggest

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have problem with writing in TypeScript & ReactJS. I have no idea how to import external libraries and use them properly in the code.

I'm trying to use `react-autosuggest` in my project so I'm:

1. Installing `react-autosuggest` with `npm install --save react-autosuggest`
2. Installing typing for this library with `typings install --global --save dt~react-autosuggest`
3. going to file where I want to use this and trying to import that and use

Here I have problem, because I still have problems with importing it.

When I'm trying to import it with `import * as autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest'` I'm getting  error

`error TS2497: Module ''react-autosuggest'' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.`

When I'm importing with `import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest'` another error appears:

`error TS1192: Module ''react-autosuggest'' has no default export.`

Could you guide me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your import use require:

```
import AutoSuggest = require("react-autosuggest");
new AutoSuggest();
```

The export of the module is done with the `export =` syntax. Refer to this SO for details on why you need to import this with require: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29598404/5324369