# How to create a typings file to export a module as a class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have some Javascript code that imports the `messageformat` module. This module can be used like this:

```
const MessageFormat = require('messageformat');
const mf = new MessageFormat("en-US");
const text = mf.compile(...);
```

This module exports a class, but it doesn't have a typings file. I created the following typings file:

```
declare module "messageformat" {
  export class MessageFormat {
    constructor(locale: string);
    public compile(messageString: string): string;
  }
}
```

In my Typescript code I now use it as:

```
import { MessageFormat } from "messageformat";
const mf = new MessageFormat("en-US");
const text = mf.compile(...);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't generate `new MessageFormat("en-US")`, but it generates `new messageformat_1.MessageFormat("en-US")` which fails. I also tried the following approach:

```
declare module "messageformat" {
  export default class MessageFormat {
    constructor(locale: string);
    public compile(messageString: string): string;
  }
}
```

In my Typescript code I now use it as:

```
import MessageFormat from "messageformat";
const mf = new MessageFormat("en-US");
const text = mf.compile(...);
```

But this compiles to `new messageformat_1.default('en-US')` which is also not correct. How do I create the typings file (and how do I import the module) so the proper class is constructed?

Comment: Your expectation is not valid. The generated code is correct in every way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29598404/956435).

It looks that the following method works:

```
declare module "messageformat" {
  class MessageFormat {
    constructor(locale: string);
    public compile(messageString: string): string;
  }

  export = MessageFormat;
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use the `import` statement anymore, but the following code seems to work:

```
import MessageFormat = require("messageformat");
const mf = new MessageFormat("en-US");
const text = mf.compile(...);
```

Although I think the `import MessageFormat = require("messageformat")` looks a bit awkward, it does work and all typings can be used.