# Why is import xxx = require('package') better than const xxx = require('package')? and is this true?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have had it suggested that:

```
import xxx = require('package');
```

is better than:

```
const xxx = require('package');
```

and keeps all the type definitions. Is this true?
It seems that the first syntax may be better, but I remain confused when import and require are used together like this.

Comment: Where did you see that syntax? It's nowhere to be found on the [MDN docs for `import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Comment: perhaps it's a typescript thing @JackBashford - with the phrase `type definitions` (probably not though) - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html has no example with `import x = require('y')`

Comment: Yes, it is Typescript syntax, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596714/new-es6-syntax-for-importing-commonjs-amd-modules-i-e-import-foo-require maybe

Comment: ahh, it's OLD syntax

Comment: *"When exporting a module using `export =`, TypeScript-specific `import module = require("module")` must be used to import the module."* (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

Answer (score 2):

`import xxx = require('package');` is the old typescript syntax for importing modules, it is recommended you switch to the new ES standard import syntax. This might not always be possible if the module does [not support it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require):

> Both CommonJS and AMD generally have the concept of an exports object which contains all exports from a module.
>
> They also support replacing the exports object with a custom single object. Default exports are meant to act as a replacement for this behavior; however, the two are incompatible. TypeScript supports export = to model the traditional CommonJS and AMD workflow.
>
> **When exporting a module using `export =`, TypeScript-specific `import module = require("module")` must be used to import the module**

If you are deciding between `import xxx = require('package')` and `const xxx = require('package')`, I would definitely use the `import` version.

The `import`version triggers the typescript machinery to resolve the module and to correctly type the import variable (taking advantage of any module definitions you have for that module).

The `const` version is **just a function call** to a function defined in the node definitions:

```
declare var require: NodeRequire;
interface NodeRequire extends NodeRequireFunction { /*...*/ }

interface NodeRequireFunction {
    (id: string): any; // just returns any.
}
```

As you can see this function returns `any` for any given module name, so in effect the variable holding the imports will be of type `any` and thus you will not benefit from any types you might have installed for the module.