# Mongoose is undefined when using import syntax and not when using require

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose, ecmascript-6, nestjs

So I have my module written as such

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export class MyModule {
   constructor(){
       //do
   }

   create(str){
      mongoose.connect(str); //cannot find property 'connect' of undefined
   }

}
```

When using the import syntax, I get the `cannot find property 'connect' of undefined` error; it works as intended when using require.

Weirdly enough, importing individual properties via import syntax works as intended,

```
import { connect } from 'mongoose'
```

but I need access to the entire ORM for some other reasons.

Why is it like so? Am I doing something wrong? To be fair, I don't have much experience in ES6 module system, TypeScript and Node.js so I might be missing something here.

---

I'm running this on Node.js with NestJS, on a typescript file.

Comment: Has it installed `mongoose` in the `node_modules`? was there any error in npm installation?

Comment: To be clear, when you replace the first line of your code example with `const mongoose = require('mongoose');` it works? Are you executing this code with Node.js?

Comment: @nivendha Yea, I have it in my package.json already and it's also existing in the node_modules folder

Comment: @PatrickHund Yes and yes, and I'm using NestJS as a framework

Comment: Import syntax mandates the file extension so `import mongoose from 'mongoose.js'`. Also, you cannot mix and match import and require syntax. Commonjs (nodejs) modules **must** use `require` and cannot use `import`. ES6 modules **must** use `import` and cannot user `require`. There is a possibility of writing modules that export both but not all do (in fact most don't)

Comment: ```import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';``` try this

Comment: The reason for this is that the ES standards committee, being mostly browser developers, have defined the behavior of ES6 module loading that is not compatible with nodejs old module system

Comment: @slebetman `import mongoose from 'mongoose.js'` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @BinitGhetiya `import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';` works amazingly! I think I also found the problem upon using this. It seems like Mongoose does not have a default export as reported by VS Code after installing `@types/mongoose`, that being the case, doing `import mongoose` explicitly will not work.

Comment: Are you using babel js for ES6

Comment: @HamidRazaNoori Either that or is a Typescript compiler thing

Comment: @AbanaClara I have added answer please mark it correct Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> There are total 2 syntex we can use here.

## ES15 (NodeJS)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

then use **mongoose.connect**

## ES16 (import/export)

```
import * as mongoose from `mongoose`;
```

then use **mongoose.connect**

#### or

```
import {connect} from `mongoose`;
```

then use **connect** directly

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work as an acceptable answer to my problem (those useful for future readers). I have personally written an answer with a decent explanation and mention your handle instead.

Comment: @AbanaClara No worries :), hope you got your answer.

Answer (score 4):

In your `tsconfig.json` file, you can set

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"esModuleInterop": true
```

This will allow you to use the syntax

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
```

Comment: Wow this is definitely good info. I wish this answer came when this post was hot.

Answer (score 2):

After installing `@types/mongoose`, VS Code reports that mongoose does not have a default export (all being named exports) that being the case, doing

```
import mongoose from `mongoose`
```

will not work. This also explains why getting individual properties instead works:

```
import { connect } from `mongoose`
```

As a workaround, thanks to @Binit Ghetiya who first mentioned it in this thread, you should do this instead:

```
import * as mongoose from `mongoose`
```

Which compiles every named export from Mongoose into the variable `mongoose`.

Answer (score 0):

**Just change the import as follows:**

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
```

**Here is an example:**

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export class MyModule {

   constructor(){
       //do
   }

   create(str){
      mongoose.connect(str);
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is a Typescript specific syntax and breaks the ES6 standards. For now it works but in the future when Typescript re-aligns with ES6 this may break (or it may not, depends on what Microsoft wants to do with the language they invented). See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596714/new-es6-syntax-for-importing-commonjs-amd-modules-i-e-import-foo-require