# Can't find export from module typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Got a file where an object is exported:

```
let btypes:{[key:string]:any} = {
"key1":val,
//...
} 
export {btypes}
```

I also tried `export default btypes`

When I import it with:

```
import {btypes} from "../types";
```

The terminal outputs:

> src/**tests**/parse.test.ts:3:8 - error TS1192: Module '"/abc/types"' has no default export.

Or

> src/**tests**/parse.test.ts:3:9 - error TS2305: Module '"../types"' has no exported member 'btypes'.

Any idea what to look for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They say: [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) (and also [in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports)):

> (...) there is a confusing part of default exports:/ Some exports have documentation that implies you can write an import like this: `import req from "request";`

> However that fails, and then you find a stack overflow  which recommends the import as: `import * as req from "request";`

which is what @Mustafa suggested for **default exports**.

There is another solution written in the playground. Add this to *tsconfig.js*:

1. **esModuleInterop:true**
2. **allowSyntheticDefaultImports:true**

Now `import myDefaultExport from './myMod';` should be enough.

Answer (score 3):

Try exporting like this:

```
export default {btypes};
```

And import like this:

```
import * as btypes from '../types';
```

Comment: But what is wrong with the shown code?

Comment: Read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596714/new-es6-syntax-for-importing-commonjs-amd-modules-i-e-import-foo-require