# `require` return is not typed properly (is `any`)

Tags: typescript, plugins, tailwind-css

I'm trying to move tailwind custom plugin logic to a separate TypeScript file, but getting typing error:

> `require` function is returning type `any` for `plugin` function.

I've tried assertion with `PluginCreator` type, which I declared in tailwind, but getting error: **Cannot find name 'PluginCreator'**.

Will appreciate any example.

[image]

Comment: Why blue line under require?

Comment: @Dimava spell checking

Comment: Try `import plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')`

Comment: @Dimava lol... That's work and solve the problem, but I woul never say it's valid syntax, but it works for real.

Could you post it as an answer, so I can mark it for others as a working solution

Comment: @Mero it is valid syntax in TypeScript. See [this discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242#issuecomment-83694181) and some of the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596714/new-es6-syntax-for-importing-commonjs-amd-modules-i-e-import-foo-require). Definitely not valid JS, and it sure looks weird to anyone comfortable with ES modules, but in TS it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper syntax for using `require` in Typescript is

```
import const_name = require('pachage_name')
```

which will compile to

```
// js
const const_name = require('pachage_name')
```

In your case, use

```
import plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')
```

---

If you can use the modern import syntax, it's better to use it already - `require` is slowly becoming outdated.

```
// the modern ESModule import syntax:
import plugin from 'tailwindcss/plugin'
```

which is compiled roughly to into the same js

```
// actuall js will have some compability wrappers
// if tsconfig `esModuleInterop` is `true` this will work the same 
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')
```

Comment: Just a minor nitpick, `import foo from 'bar'` roughly transpiles to `const foo = require('bar').default`, usually (though it depends on the transpiler).

Comment: @ZacAnger yes, that's why `esModuleInterop` adds `const foo = ({default: require('bar')}).default` wrapper for compability

Answer (score 1):

This should be imported as

```
import * as plugin from "tailwindcss/plugin";
```

To have proper types loaded, as of 2023, Typescript v5+.