# TypeScript types from required file don't transmit into a file that requires it

Tags: typescript, ts-node

Solved. See below.

## Problem

The TypeScript types from one commonjs module, don't transmit into a file that requires it:

## Main files

#### Module

`scripts/ci/publish/getTag.ts`

```js
type Release = 'alpha' | 'beta';

const getTag = ():Release => 'alpha';

module.exports = getTag;
```

#### Requiring file

`scripts/ci/publish/index.ts`

```js
const tag = require('./getTag')(); // Type "any"

console.log(`Publishing ${tag}`);

export {}; // Tell TS this top-level file is a package
```

#### Run command

I execute via, and it works.

```bash
$ ts-node ./scripts/ci/publish/index.ts

> Publishing alpha
```

## Behavior

#### Expected

Type of `const tag` should infer as `type Release`

#### Actual

Type of `const tag` infers as any

## Configuration files

`./package.json` snippet

```json
   "devDependencies": {
     "ts-node": "10.9.1",
     "types": "10.9.1"
    }
```

`./tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "ts-node/node14/tsconfig.json",
  "ts-node": {
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "files": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "types": [
        "node"
      ],
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "./scripts/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

## Solution

TS doesn't support Commonjs modules very well.

I had to change `require` to `import`

`./tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "ts-node/node14/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "files": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./scripts/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`require\` return is not typed properly (is \`any\`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76502241/require-return-is-not-typed-properly-is-any)

Comment: Also you can use async import instead or require