# Cannot use old import module with new ES6 import syntax with typescript

Tags: typescript, bluebird

I have an issue where I am dependent upon the great Bluebird library, however the typescript descriptor suffers from `export = theModule` issue (as discussed here [TypeScript 1.5: ES6 Module default import of CommonJS 'export =' (.d.ts only issue?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593126/typescript-1-5-es6-module-default-import-of-commonjs-export-d-ts-only-iss))

So I have applied the workaround:

`import * as bluebird from "bluebird";`

Which at least progresses things, but then if I were to try and use the static methods like so:

`return Promise
            .resolve(someObject)
            .then(doSomething);`

It blows up telling me it requires a generic, which it should not do for this, and even if I provide a generic at the `Promise` or `resolve` level it just then blows up on it expecting brackets.

Anyone else had a similar issue and found a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is not with the code shown in my example but with the return type needing to be typed correctly, after sorting that the problem goes away, so really this is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
import * as bluebird, {Promise} from "bluebird";
```

Comment: Throws errors `(1,21): error TS1005: 'from' expected.`, `(1,33): error TS1005: ';' expected.` and `(1,38): error TS1005: ';' expected.`