# ES6 module syntax for multiple "static" functions

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

I'm coming from Java, and trying to turn the idea of a "utility class" into something that works in ES6.

In my file `numbers.js`, I can export a single function:

```
export default function padDigits(number, digits) {
    return new Array(Math.max(digits - String(number).length + 1, 0)).join(0) + number;
}
```

Which can then be imported in another file like:

```
import padDigits from '../utils/numbers';
...
var paddedNum = padDigits(myNum, 2);
```

**However:** I would like for two things to be possible: I want to (1) export multiple functions from this single file, and (2) I would like for them to be accessible via a single import statement, and called via a namespace/classname prefix, like:

```
import Numbers from '../utils/numbers';
...
var paddedNum = Numbers.padDigits(myNum, 2);
var truncatedNum = Numbers.truncate(myNum, 3);
```

But I'm having a hard time finding the right syntax to accomplish this.

Comment: Read up on ES6 module syntax. A good reference is http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you perhaps looking for the wildcard?

```js
import * as nums from '../utils/numbers';
```

A similiar question: [TypeScript 1.5: ES6 Module default import of CommonJS 'export =' (.d.ts only issue?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593126/typescript-1-5-es6-module-default-import-of-commonjs-export-d-ts-only-iss)

A more detailed answer into this: [New es6 syntax for importing commonjs / amd modules i.e. `import foo = require('foo')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596714/new-es6-syntax-for-importing-commonjs-amd-modules-i-e-import-foo-require/29598404#29598404)